# Does signal frequency affect the band width of SDR hardware?

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio, frequency, bandwidth, usrp

I am new to SDR,already owned USRP B210 and start to learn Gnuradio.

I have follow question:
B210 has max bind width 56Mhz.When I use max sample rate to received signal,does the signal frequency(433Mhz or 2.4Ghz) affect (decrease or increse) the available band width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SDR receivers which use a mixer in front of the ADC to receive radio spectrum above the ADC sample rate(s), the sample rates and down-conversion frequency are usually independent settable (except possibly for the very bottom end of the range in some SDRs which don’t work (well?) for center frequencies below the sample rate.)

Comment: The answer is yes? or no?